# check with spell checker control in smith html editor

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using a smith html editor to control older version (1.0.0.0). if any latest version is available in the smith html editor. how to add with spell checker control in the editor window. can you give me a quick response.....

Answer (score 0):

If you have source code then you make this below code change and it does the spell check.

In **HtmlEditor.xaml.cs** file add this line

```
VisualEditor.Document.Body.SetAttribute("spellcheck", "true");
```

in **OnVisualEditorDocumentNavigated** method

```
private void OnVisualEditorDocumentNavigated(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{            
        VisualEditor.Document.ContextMenuShowing += this.OnDocumentContextMenuShowing;
        htmldoc = new HtmlDocument(VisualEditor.Document);
        //((IHTMLDocument2)VisualEditor.Document.DomDocument).designMode = "ON";
        SetStylesheet();
        SetInitialContent();
        VisualEditor.Document.Body.SetAttribute("contenteditable", "true");             
        VisualEditor.Document.Body.SetAttribute("spellcheck", "true");
        VisualEditor.Document.Focus();
}
```